# Reading PORT number from .env file in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, backend, nestjs-config

I have details defined in `.env` file. Below is my code.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailService } from './mail.service';
import { MailController } from './mail.controller';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { HandlebarsAdapter}  from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { join } from 'path';


@Module({
  imports:[
     MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport:{
        host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
        port: 1025,
        ignoreTLS: true,
        secure: false,
        auth:{
          user:'shruti.sharma@infosys.com',
          pass:'Ddixit90@@',
        },
      },
      defaults:{
           from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@localhost>',
      },
      template:{
        dir:join(__dirname,'templates'),
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options:{
          strict:false,
        },
      }
     }
      
     )
  ],
  controllers: [MailController],
  providers: [MailService],
  exports:[MailService]
})
export class MailModule {}
```

`host: process.env.SMTP_HOST` is working properly. but when I am writing `process.env.SMTP_PORT` it is saying you can not assign string to number.
[image]

when I wrote `parseInt(process.env.SMTP_PORT)` it is still not working. how to assign `port` from `.env` file

Comment: Please explain "when I wrote parseInt(process.env.SMTP_PORT) it is still not working". Share errors, not tiny screenshots of errors.

Comment: How do you read from the `.env` file? Are you using `@nestjs/config` or `dotenv` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`port: +process.env.SMTP_PORT` should work casting it to a number. If there is something different, perhaps share the error you are getting.

An alternative would be to use the config service for the MailerModule and use the factory. Here is an example implementation of that:

```
MailerModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
                transport: {
                    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
                    port: 1025,
                    ignoreTLS: true,
                    secure: false,
                    auth: {
                        user: "shruti.sharma@infosys.com",
                        pass: "Ddixit90@@",
                    },
                },
                defaults: {
                    from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@localhost>',
                },
                template: {
                    dir: join(__dirname, "templates"),
                    adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
                    options: {
                        strict: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
```

Doing it this way, config.get is able to determine the type by the property. Else you can define it with `config.get<number>`